# Realm Java Android: Create or update object

Tags: java, android, realm, realm-java

In Realm Javascript, it's possible to create an object by primary key and, if it already exists, update the existing object: https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#creating-and-updating-objects-with-primary-keys

How can I achieve the same in Realm Java? Didn't find this function in the docs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How can I achieve the same in Realm Java? Didn't find this function in the docs.

There are two methods for this,

1.) [copyToRealmOrUpdate()](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/Realm.html#copyToRealmOrUpdate-E-) which returns the managed proxy

2.) [insertOrUpdate()](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/Realm.html#insertOrUpdate-io.realm.RealmModel-) which does not return the managed proxy (so it's faster when you insert many items)